# Error: EADDRINUSE on Mac - even though nothing is using the port?

Tags: node.js

```
Alexs-MacBook-Pro:build alexnordhausen$ gulp server:start
[21:11:22] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Kanvasroom_Support/kanvasroom/build/gulpfile.js
[21:11:22] Starting 'env:dev'...
Application loaded using the "development" environment configuration

[21:11:22] Finished 'env:dev' after 6.25 ms
[21:11:22] Starting 'server:start'...
[21:11:22] Finished 'server:start' after 1.95 ms
[21:11:22] [nodemon] 1.11.0
[21:11:22] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[21:11:22] [nodemon] watching: *.*
[21:11:22] [nodemon] starting `node --debug=5858 --trace-warnings server.js`
Server started, be sure the user content server is also running with gulp user-content
Live-build the client with gulp web:dist

Debugger listening on 127.0.0.1:5858
[Busy] Launching SocketCluster
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:5858
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
at listen (net.js:1298:10)
at doListening (net.js:1397:7)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

There aren't any ghost processes running... this was working just fine until I did a fresh npm install of the whole project. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the logs, you are using clustering. You might be trying to listen from each child process on same port, which will throw error after when second child process got launched.

Comment: I didn't need to do this prior?

Comment: @Alex You should listen in master process, and try to manage tasks with child process using other way.

Comment: But again, this was working literally 30 minutes ago. I changed nothing other than pulling a fresh set of code from my repo.

Comment: @Alex It shouldn't have worked. You can check if multiple listen calls were made previously.

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your log:

Your master server started on 127.0.0.1:5858.

Then SocketCluster try to starting on 127.0.0.1:5858

So if you one server is already 5858 port, Then how can other server use 5858 ?

So plese change the port for solving the issue.

Answer (score -1):

This error comes when more then two app using a single portno.

```
Use this command 
1) `netstat -tulpn` (Commans for show all the process on server) 
2)  then kill the process with the process number. like kill 2043
```